# Making files uploaded to s3 public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm using s3-swf-upload-plugin in a Rails project to upload directly to S3.  Pretty nifty, but can't seem to figure out how to make the uploaded files public.  S3 doesn't seem to have the concept of public "buckets".  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use S3Fox for Firefox, http://www.s3fox.net/

You can browse your S3 buckets then right-click -> Edit ACL and set things to public.

You can also get the url for the bucket in a similar fashion.

It is very simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

S3 supports four different access policies for both buckets and objects.

Take a look at the **Canned Access Policies** section in [the S3 Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/index.html?RESTAccessPolicy.html#RESTCannedAccessPolicies).

Specifically:

- private
- public-read
- public-read-write
- authenticated-read

So in your case, you'll need set the access policy on your bucket and uploaded files to **public-read**.

Comment: That link to the s3 documentation is broken. Does anyone have a link to the canned access policies section of their current documentation? (I have been searching but cannot find it.)